# Using left join to get a user's all activities on a page from four tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Please take a look at this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b7d60) (Updated)

Suppose I have the user's facebook id `FB1111` and the product model number `CCC`, how can I retrieve the user's like/dislike and bookmark record on the product from tables `BOOKMARK` and `LIKE_DISLIKE` that use foreign keys?

Table `BOOKMARK` stores a user's bookmark record on a product when he clicks on the bookmark button on the product page. `1` means he has bookmarked it and `0` means he has unbookmarked it, the same goes for the `LIKE_TYPE` field in table `LIKE_DISLIKE`

I'm at a loss on joining so many tables and the where clause. Is LEFT JOIN the correct way of doing that?

Here's the output I'm trying to get, despite the fact that Tom doesn't have any activity on ToyC:

```
NAME   MODEL  ISBOOKED  LIKE_TYPE
TOM    ToyC   NULL      NULL
```

Failed Attempt:

```
SELECT a.NAME,c.MODEL,b.ISBOOKED,d.LIKE_TYPE
  FROM `USER_ID` a 
         LEFT JOIN `BOOKMARK` b 
         ON b.USER_ID = a.USER_ID           
         LEFT JOIN `MODEL_ID` c
         ON c.MODEL_ID = b.MODEL_ID
         LEFT JOIN `LIKE_DISLIKE` d
         ON d.MODEL_ID = c.MODEL_ID
         WHERE a.FACEBOOK_ID = 'FB1111'
         AND c.MODEL_NUMBER = 'CCC'
         AND ( ?? OR ??)
```

Here's the table schema

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKMARK
    (`USER_ID` int, `MODEL_ID` int,`ISBOOKED`int)
;

INSERT INTO BOOKMARK
    (`USER_ID`,`MODEL_ID`,`ISBOOKED`)
VALUES
    (1, '2','1'),
    (2, '3','0'),
    (1, '1','1'),
    (2, '2','1')
;

CREATE TABLE LIKE_DISLIKE
    (`USER_ID` int,`MODEL_ID`int, `LIKE_TYPE` int)
;

INSERT INTO LIKE_DISLIKE
    (`USER_ID`,`MODEL_ID`,`LIKE_TYPE`)
VALUES
    (1, '1','0'),
    (2, '2','1'),
    (1,'2','1')
;


CREATE TABLE MODEL_ID
    (`MODEL_ID` int, `MODEL` varchar(20),`MODEL_NUMBER` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO MODEL_ID
    (`MODEL_ID`,`MODEL`,`MODEL_NUMBER`)
VALUES
    (1, 'ToyA','AAA'),
    (2, 'ToyB','BBB'),
    (3, 'ToyC','CCC')
;

CREATE TABLE USER_ID
    (`USER_ID` int, `NAME` varchar(20),`FACEBOOK_ID` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO USER_ID
    (`USER_ID`,`NAME`,`FACEBOOK_ID`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Tom','FB1111'),
    (2, 'Peter','FB2222')
;


ALTER TABLE BOOKMARK
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_bookmark_user_id
FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER_ID(USER_ID) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE BOOKMARK
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_bookmark_model_id 
FOREIGN KEY (MODEL_ID) REFERENCES MODEL_ID(MODEL_ID) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE LIKE_DISLIKE
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_like_type_user_id
FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER_ID(USER_ID) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE LIKE_DISLIKE
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_like_type_model_id 
FOREIGN KEY (MODEL_ID) REFERENCES MODEL_ID(MODEL_ID) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your params at the bottom:

```
   SELECT ui.NAME,mi.MODEL,b.ISBOOKED,ld.LIKE_TYPE
     FROM `USER_ID` ui
     JOIN `MODEL_ID` mi
LEFT JOIN `BOOKMARK` b 
       ON b.USER_ID = ui.USER_ID
      AND b.MODEL_ID = mi.MODEL_ID         
LEFT JOIN `LIKE_DISLIKE` ld 
       ON ld.USER_ID = ui.USER_ID
      AND ld.MODEL_ID = mi.MODEL_ID 
    WHERE ui.FACEBOOK_ID = 'FB1111'
      AND mi.MODEL_NUMBER = 'CCC'
```

Else I prefer:

```
   SELECT ui.NAME,mi.MODEL,b.ISBOOKED,ld.LIKE_TYPE
     FROM `USER_ID` ui
     JOIN `MODEL_ID` mi
       ON mi.MODEL_NUMBER = 'CCC'
LEFT JOIN `BOOKMARK` b 
       ON b.USER_ID = ui.USER_ID
      AND b.MODEL_ID = mi.MODEL_ID         
LEFT JOIN `LIKE_DISLIKE` ld 
       ON ld.USER_ID = ui.USER_ID
      AND ld.MODEL_ID = mi.MODEL_ID 
    WHERE ui.FACEBOOK_ID = 'FB1111'
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate answer to your question is to move the condition on the `c` table to the `on` clause.  It is turning the `left outer join` into an `inner join`:

```
SELECT a.NAME,c.MODEL,b.ISBOOKED,d.LIKE_TYPE
FROM `USER_ID` a 
         LEFT JOIN `BOOKMARK` b 
         ON b.USER_ID = a.USER_ID           
         LEFT JOIN `MODEL_ID` c
         ON c.MODEL_ID = b.MODEL_ID AND c.MODEL_NUMBER = 'CCC'
         LEFT JOIN `LIKE_DISLIKE` d
         ON d.MODEL_ID = c.MODEL_ID
WHERE a.FACEBOOK_ID = 'FB1111';
```

I suspect that when you run this query on users that have multiple rows in more than one of the tables, though, you will not like the results.  When that happens, ask another question.